# Is there a way Automate sphinx-apidoc generation in readthedocs

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, sphinx-apidoc

I'm somewhat new at both these tool sets.

Currently I am running `sphinx-apidoc...` and then checking in the resulting `doc/source/*.rst` files so that `readthedocs` produces more than an empty document.

However; is there a way to have this done automatically during the `readthedoc` build process?

It would save remembering to build and checkin all the `*.rst` files in `doc/source` on the repo.

Comment: That's the thing... it's not stable as the project is fairly new so things will change frequently.

Comment: @mzjn The `pre-build` option on the second reference looks promising, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of executing an extra command on Read the Docs is using the "Build customization" feature via `build.jobs` configuration option. See the docs at https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build-customization.html

You can do the following in your case:

```yaml
# .readthedocs.yaml
version: 2

build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: 3
  jobs:
    pre_build:
     - sphinx-apidoc ...
```

Hopefully that works for you!